# How do I resolve libarclite path error produced after updating to Xcode 15

Tags: xcode

After updating mac os to Sonoma and updating Xcode to 15, this error comes out:

> SDK does not contain 'libarclite' at the path '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/codeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/arc/libarclite_iphonesimulator.a; try increasing the minimum deployment target

I tried reinstalling, entered the commands specified in similar questionnaires, but nothing helped. Nothing works out. Please help me, I am a novice developer

[image]

Reinstalling, entering various codes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [clang: error: SDK does not contain 'libarclite' at the path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77139617/clang-error-sdk-does-not-contain-libarclite-at-the-path)