# iOS build failure: libarclite missing

Tags: ios, xcode

receiving build error:
clang: error: SDK does not contain 'libarclite' at the path '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/arc/libarclite_iphonesimulator.a'; try increasing the minimum deployment target

not sure how to resolve

Comment: I had to delete some SDKs today and reinstall. Got a ton of errors all of a sudden. Go into settings in Xcode.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [clang: error: SDK does not contain 'libarclite' at the path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77139617/clang-error-sdk-does-not-contain-libarclite-at-the-path) or [Missing file libarclite_iphoneos.a (Xcode 14.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75574268/missing-file-libarclite-iphoneos-a-xcode-14-3?rq=2)

Answer (score 0):

I found a suggestion to select Pods -> Targets, and change the IOS Deployment Target.  I changed the target version to the same version as my app, and that cleared up most of the issues.

[screen capture of Xcode UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tCQI.png)