# ERROR | xcodebuild: Returned an unsuccessful exit code

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

## Report

As you can see in the following, I set my pod ***in the pod file to support version 14.0*** . but as you can see ***in the error the used version is 8.0*** or different.
I think this is the source of my issue.

#### pod file:

```
source 'https://cdn.cocoapods.org/'

install! 'cocoapods', :warn_for_unused_master_specs_repo => false

workspace 'ApesterKit.xcworkspace'

project 'ApesterKit.xcodeproj'

platform :ios, '13.0'

use_frameworks!

target 'ApesterKit_Example' do
  pod 'ApesterObjcBridging', :path => '../' ;
  pod 'ApesterKit'         , :path => '../' , :appspecs => ['zHostApp'] , :testspecs => ['zUnitTests','zUITests'];
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.generated_projects.each do |project|
    project.targets.each do |target|
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '14.0'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

### What did you do?

1. > run pod install - completed succesfully
2. > pod cache --clean-all
3. > pod lib lint ApesterKit.podspec

```
-> ApesterKit (3.3.15)
    - NOTE  | [ApesterKit/Content_Core, ApesterKit/ContentAdmob, ApesterKit/ContentPubmatic, and more...] xcodebuild:  note: Using codesigning identity override: -
    - NOTE  | [ApesterKit/Content_Core, ApesterKit/ContentAdmob, ApesterKit/ContentPubmatic, and more...] xcodebuild:  note: Building targets in dependency order
    - NOTE  | [ApesterKit/ContentAmazon,ApesterKit/Content] xcodebuild:  note: Target dependency graph (10 targets)
    - NOTE  | [ApesterKit/Content_Core, ApesterKit/ContentAdmob, ApesterKit/ContentPubmatic, and more...] xcodebuild:  note: Signing static framework with --generate-pre-encrypt-hashes (in target 'ApesterObjcBridging' from project 'Pods')
    - NOTE  | [ApesterKit/ContentAmazon,ApesterKit/Content] xcodebuild:  Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 12.0 to 17.2.99. (in target 'OpenWrapHandlerDFP' from project 'Pods')
    - NOTE  | [ApesterKit/Content_Core, ApesterKit/ContentAdmob, ApesterKit/ContentPubmatic, and more...] xcodebuild:  note: Signing static framework with --generate-pre-encrypt-hashes (in target 'ApesterKit' from project 'Pods')
    - NOTE  | [ApesterKit/Content_Core, ApesterKit/ContentAdmob, ApesterKit/ContentPubmatic, and more...] xcodebuild:  note: Signing static framework with --generate-pre-encrypt-hashes (in target 'Pods-App' from project 'Pods')
    - NOTE  | [ApesterKit/Content_Core, ApesterKit/ContentAdmob, ApesterKit/ContentPubmatic, and more...] xcodebuild:  note: Metadata extraction skipped. No AppIntents.framework dependency found. (in target 'App' from project 'App')
    - NOTE  | [ApesterKit/Content_Core, ApesterKit/ContentAdmob, ApesterKit/ContentPubmatic, and more...] xcodebuild:  Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 12.0 to 17.2.99. (in target 'DTBiOSSDK' from project 'Pods')
    - NOTE  | [ApesterKit/Content_Core, ApesterKit/ContentAdmob, ApesterKit/ContentPubmatic, and more...] xcodebuild:  Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 12.0 to 17.2.99. (in target 'OpenWrapSDK' from project 'Pods')
    - ERROR | xcodebuild: Returned an unsuccessful exit code.
    - NOTE  | xcodebuild:  note: Target dependency graph (14 targets)
    - NOTE  | xcodebuild:  Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 12.0 to 17.2.99. (in target 'EzImageLoader' from project 'Pods')
    - NOTE  | xcodebuild:  Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 12.0 to 17.2.99. (in target 'XCGLogger' from project 'Pods')
    - NOTE  | xcodebuild:  clang: error: SDK does not contain 'libarclite' at the path '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/arc/libarclite_iphonesimulator.a'; try increasing the minimum deployment target
    - NOTE  | xcodebuild:  Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 12.0 to 17.2.99. (in target 'EzHTTP' from project 'Pods')
    - NOTE  | xcodebuild:  Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 12.0 to 17.2.99. (in target 'ObjcExceptionBridging' from project 'Pods')
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  rsync error: received SIGINT, SIGTERM, or SIGHUP (code 20) at /AppleInternal/Library/BuildRoots/11aa8fb2-5f4b-11ee-bc7f-926038f30c31/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync/rsync.c(244) [sender=2.6.9]
    - NOTE  | [ApesterKit/Content_Core,ApesterKit/ContentPubmatic] xcodebuild:  note: Target dependency graph (6 targets)
    - NOTE  | [iOS] [ApesterKit/ContentAdmob] xcodebuild:  note: Target dependency graph (8 targets)

Pods workspace available at `/var/folders/9g/h5_gqgjs30n11p7w8l_q1lzc0000gp/T/CocoaPods-Lint-20240307-5239-gcdhdl-ApesterKit/App.xcworkspace` for inspection.

[!] ApesterKit did not pass validation, due to 1 error.

/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/command/lib/lint.rb:116:in `block in run'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/command/lib/lint.rb:77:in `each'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/command/lib/lint.rb:77:in `run'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/bin/pod:25:in `load'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/bin/pod:25:in `<main>'
```

#### Stack

- CocoaPods : 1.15.2

  - Ruby : ruby 3.3.0 (2023-12-25 revision 5124f9ac75) [x86_64-darwin23]
- RubyGems : 3.5.4
- ```
    Host : macOS 14.1.1 (23B81)
  ```
- ```
  Xcode : 15.2 (15C500b)
  ```
- ```
   Git : git version 2.39.3 (Apple Git-145)
  ```

- Ruby lib dir : /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/3.3.0/lib
- Repositories : trunk - CDN - https://cdn.cocoapods.org/
  Installation Source
- Executable Path: /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/bin/pod

#### Plugins

- cocoapods-deintegrate : 1.0.5
- cocoapods-plugins     : 1.0.0
- cocoapods-search      : 1.0.1
- cocoapods-trunk       : 1.6.0
- cocoapods-try         : 1.2.0

## Project that demonstrates the issue

[link to repo in cocoapods](https://cocoapods.org/pods/ApesterKit)

[link to github repo](https://github.com/apester-dev/ios-sdk.)

any ideas or any information I need to add that might help you assist me :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [clang: error: SDK does not contain 'libarclite' at the path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77139617/clang-error-sdk-does-not-contain-libarclite-at-the-path)

Comment: No mate, i did already change my pods version, but the used version of the pods when im linting is still the old version.

Comment: Ah, it's a private pod, right? You can't run post_install for that. It's not about the pods version.

In order to pass the lint, you need to either update your dependencies, downgrade Xcode (to 14.X), or try other methods in the linked question.